# Rename Android Studio project causing a bunch of errors and java files missing

Tags: android-studio

Following some links here I tried to rename a project. I went to *c:\path\to\AndroidStudioProject* and renamed the folder there, then found the *.idea* file and changed that. Now the project loads but java files are missing! However, on clicking java (in the bar at the top), then com I can see them each with a *small red j*.
I then looked in module Gradle build where there were 3 files, one with the new name and 2 older ones which stated that they did not belong so I deleted them, copying the compile info into the new one. Naturally on doing a *Sync Now* I get a bunch of errors.
Why does this have to be such a complex operation? Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you rename the folder, open the project in Android Studio.  From there, right click something that needs to be renamed (e.g., module, package names, etc.) and use `Refactor->Rename` from the context menu. Keep doing this until everything that can be refactored is.

You will need to manually change the value of `applicationId` in the app-level `build.gradle`. Obviously, things like `@string/app_name` will also have to be changed manually. I recommend making these manual adjustments from inside Android Studio rather than directly editing the files. That way you'll know immediately if you break something.

Comment: Problem is that there is no build.gradle _(module)_ file anymore, only a _(project)_ one. I will look again and get back later.

Comment: I am getting weird messages telling me I can only edit comments for 5 minutes, hence this one: Here is the error message: `Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:The project 'Test' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Gradle settings The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin`

What plugin? This is most confusing.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851230/android-gradle-build-error9-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile.  Are you sure you put things back in the right `build.gradle`?

Comment: I followed that link and removed  some compile lines leaving only those below but get  another error `dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }` . The build.gradle(module) is missing. How can I create another one? This is the new error: ` Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Task 'generateDebugSources' not found in project ':app'.`

Comment: Make sure the `build.gradle` files are in the right folders. Use Explorer to open the project folder. The top should contain a `build.grade` containing a comment about being the top level build file.  It should not have any `compile` lines, just the `classpath`. Drill into the `app` folder and make sure it contains another `build.gradle`. That one should have an `android{}` block with `defaultConfig{}`, and a `dependencies{}` block with `compile` lines. It should start with `apply`. Sounds like the second one of these (in the `app` folder) is not in the right place or is missing something.

Comment: We are slowly progressing. I have copied the relevant files from another project into the correct places and it all loads BUT
I then get a message _Language level changed. Language level changes will take effect on project reload. Reload now? OK/Cancel_
This line of code now gives an error _Collection = new ArrayList<>(); Diamond types are not supported at this language level_. So
how do I change the language level please?

Comment: Fixed. I just had to reload Android Studio. Thank you, Paul, for your help. Never will I fiddle with Gradle again!

Comment: Really glad you got the last one taken care of because I had no clue! Nice to hear you're back in business.