# Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android studio 1.4
gradle version 2.4
android plugin version 1.3.0

> Error:(7, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'android()'
>
> Possible causes:
>
> The project 'Up_13_7_2015' may be using a
>   version of Gradle that does not contain the method. Gradle settings
>
> The build file
>   may be missing a Gradle plugin. Apply
>   Gradle plugin

**Build.gradle** file is

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }

        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')


    }
}
dependencies {
    apply plugin: 'announce'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':Downloads:Android-ViewPagerIndicator-master:library')
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Look for the errors in your project-level `build.gradle` file and fix them.

In my case the issue appeared when I added new library module to the project. My `build.gradle` looked like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' '1.3.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

As you can see this line is incorrect:

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50' '1.3.31'
```

I changed it to

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
```

and I'm not getting the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The `compile` statements must be in the app module's `build.gradle`
so if you remove them from this files and add them there, it'll work.

Comment: there's a `build.gradle` file in the root of the project and there's a `build.gradle` file in your `app` folder, I meant the latter

Comment: @android also you should take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26851467/772357)

Comment: i did not have any app folder i exported my project from eclipse....is that a problem...

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

at the top of you app module `build.gradle` file, before the `android { }`.

Comment: after adding that it is showing Error:(4, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
"openFile:/home/data/AndroidStudioProjects/Up_13_7_2015/build.gradle">Open File

Comment: So, what's in your project root level build.gradle then?

Comment: the above file is in root level build.gradle

Comment: The `android` stuff goes to a module (subdirectory) specific build.gradle, not the project-level that usually just configures repositories and so on.

Comment: i exported my project from eclipse and it is showing only  one build.gradle file in my project....is that a problem..