# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android

I had this gradle error.

> Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

I have tried refering to similar questions but it did not work.

[Android gradle build Error:(9, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851230/android-gradle-build-error9-0-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile)

[Getting Error "Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'" when Syncing Build.Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156428/getting-error-gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile-when-syncing-build-grad)

[Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730117/unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-compile)

My `build.gradle` code is here

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

`build.gradle(Module.app)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.simplemaker.pushtest"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730117/unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-compile)

Answer (score 111, accepted):

As the note of your project's `build.gradle` file suggests:

```
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
// in the individual module build.gradle files
```

Remove the 2 compile statements in that gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
```

And then make your other (module's) `build.gradle` dependencies look like this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'
}
```

Comment: What if my android project has no modules?

Comment: i ws using com.android.support:support-compat:23.0.0 bt it was com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0

Answer (score 35):

I am using Android studio based on IntelliJ Idea and I have changed Settings on when and how to wrap code. Also I had 'reformat automatically' options which lead to formatting Gradle files randomly. So it lead to something like this:

```
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0' compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
```

Gradle then fails to find compile() for the second compile. As you only allowed to write one dependency per line.

Comment: This is another possibility why this error can occur @Drew

Comment: Ok, it kinda reads like a question. Didn't want to get it deleted

Comment: Thank you, I just found IDEA really reformatted my Gradle file and made two line in one. You answer works for me.

Comment: Some extra detail would be handy here

Comment: @ChrisNevill what do you mean?

Comment: Details about where the settings you mention are in IntelliJ / Android Studio.
However I think this is actually a bug - rather than the settings - as I had not changed any settings in my setup.

Comment: That was it, in my case.
I had some row containing both "compile" and "annotationProcessor" definitions, just put them in different rows.

Answer (score 31):

Its really silly problem and I got solution:

as compile statements goes in one line

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okHttpVersion"    compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion"    compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"
```

I just changed next by next line and solved my problem:

```
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okHttpVersion"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:$okHttpVersion"
compile "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okHttpVersion"
compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$gsonVersion"
```

Hope it will helps you. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly this... for some reason something had pulled my compile statements onto one line

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844572/android-studio-broke-up-my-build-gradle-file-after-add-a-fragment

Comment: I've had some success in changing the " to '

Comment: Where I was using a string I've had some success in doing:
compile myString + ''
(that's two empty comma's)

Comment: Was facing the same problem and this is the solution!

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem, what a silly mistake :(

Answer (score 8):

Check your **build.gradle** files, sometimes when you add a module to your current module using the project settings, the **build.gradle** of current module is corrupted, and indents are broken, just check current **build.gradle** and check if all the compile statements are issued in a new line!

Comment: This is exactly what happened when I updated "signing" configuration in Module Settings.

Answer (score 7):

in addition to proper replies already given above - a picture for more detailed explanation:

[image]

Project has 2 build.gradle. You need the highlighted one: 
build.gradle (Module: app)

Answer (score 2):

Check your project.
there is 2 build.gradle.

> Move your compile line to another build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Application dependencies must include in **app -> build.gradle** file. Not in Project -> build.gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

A simple mistake can cause this problem too, don't include `classpath` dependencies to `build.gradle(Module:app)`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting this error because I had a dependency implementation line outside the `dependencies` block. Something like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    ...
  }

implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
```

**Note that all implementation calls must be defined within the dependencies block.** That's the simple fix.

I hope this helps someone out there.

Merry coding!