# Android studio complie file

Tags: android

I want to compile jar file in Android Studio. But it come out error say "Could not find property file on org.gradle.api;interna.

Here is the code:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
    compile file 'libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to download the jars and add to libs, you can use the jcenter repo to add the dependency, replace compile file 'libs/jtds-1.2.7.jar' for

```
compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.3.1'
```

If you want to search for other dependencies you can search here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.jtds/jtds/1.3.1

Comment: Error:Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile