# Integrating Flurry on Android Studio: Gradle DSL Method not found - 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, flurry, flurry-analytics

I'm following the instructions for integrating Flurry Analytics using the  [official tutorial](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/)

I run into the problem that has been widely reported:

> Error:(4, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
>   Possible causes:
>
> The project 'My_Project' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
>   Open Gradle wrapper file
>
> The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
>   Apply Gradle plugin

Here's the gradle file for the FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0 module autogenerated by Studio:

```
configurations.create("default")
artifacts.add("default", file('FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar'))
dependencies {
    compile files('FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar')
}
```

I'm aware that a common solution prescribed in such questions as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile) is to avoid putting the 'dependencies' closure in the top level build file. However, I don't have any non-gradle dependencies in that file, as is shown below.

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compile` option is a part of the Android Gradle Plugin.

You need to apply that plugin to your module's build.gradle file if the module is an Android module.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' // Android Gradle Pllugin

android {
    // Your Android configuration
}
```

With Jar:

```
dependencies {
    compile files('FlurryAnalytics-5.5.0.jar') // Your Jar
}
```

or Maven Dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0' // Latest Jcenter release
}
```

Comment: This makes sense. I had wanted to make Flurry a module of its own. What  a mistake. Well, thank you!
It'd be nice to have Flurry available on one of the Maven repos so we don't have to deal with jars at all :)

Comment: I'm just about to add flurry to my app, and looked for it on http://gradleplease.appspot.com/ which gave me back compile 'io.segment.analytics.android:flurry:1.3.1'. Are you guys really saying that flurry isn't on gradle/maven yet!!??

Comment: @RussWheeler It is on Jcenter.