# How do I get Android studio to use Flickr API?

Tags: android, flickr

I need to use Flickr AI in an Android app but I'm not sure how to get Android to recognize the API. I downloaded some unofficial jars but I couldn't get Android Studio to recognize them and I'm a bit at a loss. I want it to recognize the methods from the flickr API.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a directory called libs and put the jar in there and add this to your build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}
```

Comment: I tried that it said Gradle DSL method not found 'compile()'. Also I assume you wanted libs in the 'app' folder?

Comment: Seem my update, and also readt this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile