# Android studio broke up my build.gradle file after add a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, osx-elcapitan

Using Android Studio 2.0 over El Capitan like the next screenshot said:
[image: Android Studio 2.0 on El Capitan]

I found a bug that I can't report:
After add a Fragment to my project, AS screw up my module build.gradle file. I mean, before add the fragment they file looks like this screenshot:
[image: build.gradle dependence screenshot]

but after add the Fragment AS screw it in this way:
[image: build.gradle dependence screenshot 2]

The way to reproduce it is like I'm showing in next screenshot:
[image]

I can fix it manually, but its so annoying doing it every single time that I add a Fragment. Is there anyway to fix it?

I'm on Mac OX with El Capitan.

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce? File > New > Fragment? I almost always do File > New > Java class, anyways

Comment: Yeah, something like that: select the desired folder in project panel (left side by default), cmd+n, Fragment. I'm going to add another screenshot to show it.

Comment: they have not fixed this bug. A workaround is copy the dependecies in a different file and just copy past when AS screw it up.

Comment: same problem.. i just use right click on gradle file then git->revert after adding a fragment to bring it back..

Answer (score 17):

It is a still open bug, you can monitor it's state [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=198459)

The bug is due to the comments in the dependencies section, a temporal fix could be to remove them from there. I placed the comments there for a reason too :)

Answer (score 4):

Delete all comments in your gradle file

Comment: No idea why someone vote down but for me, it count like a work around (giving a vote up ;) ). I mean, like afj88 said its a bug related to comments but if you don't care about comments the solution you gave is fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer as to why this would work?  This seems more apt for a comment than an answer.
P.S.  I haven't downvoted you, because I don't have the full context, but the answer seems inadequate.

Answer (score 0):

put your constraint-layout on the bottom, it will not scramble again (i don't know why, but it works)

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // support lib
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportlib_version"

    // kotlin
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

    // ...

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I'm going to check it asap and tell you if it works :)

Answer (score -1):

just reformat your project level gradle . It will work fine. These compile statement got dis-formatted. Just hit Enter before every "compile"
it should be like:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
```

[image: img]

Comment: Ty vishu for the answer but I'm looking a way to avoid reformat my project every time.