# Why these dependencies are getting rearranged in build.gradle ? : Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I'm using Android Studio 2.3. In my **app level** build gradle, I have these dependencies.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Not all the time, but some times when I run my app after few modifications in my source code (Activities basically). It rearranges the order as shown below and gives me a build error in `LogCat`. why ?

```
compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'compile
    'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'compile
    'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'compile
    'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'compile
    'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.4'compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug, report it here https://developer.android.com/studio/report-bugs.html

Comment: Have you found the answer? Is this a bug? Did you report? I encounter same behavior of AS so I'm curious whether I should report or not.

Comment: Yes I've reported it today only coz I faced this problem again. @AlexBerdnikov

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android studio broke up my build.gradle file after add a Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844572/android-studio-broke-up-my-build-gradle-file-after-add-a-fragment)

Answer (score -3):

have you tried using the 
    compile('com.frebase..')

instead?