# Gradle DSL method not found: 'compileOnly()'

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, spring-boot

I'm trying to add new module to my application. I successfully added movie-api module (you can see in picture below), but when I try to add another module (client-app), I'm getting error as shown in picture.
[image]

I tried with different solutions including [Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile), but didn't work for me.
Appreciate your help!

Build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'client-app'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: Show your build.gradle file.  Sounds like you don't have the java plugin applied or something is breaking the parsing.  Can you build via command line?  If not what does `build -s` task output?  Also check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JBirdVegas , here is my build.gradle

Comment: @JBirdVegas I've added my build.gradle. Would you please look into it? Thank you :)

Comment: Please also post the contents of `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`.  From the screen cap looks like your using the wrapper so perhaps the wrapper is using an old version of gradle. Latest is `3.2.1`

Answer (score 5):

`compileOnly` was introduced in Gradle 2.12. Make sure you are using a new enough version, with both the command-line and the IDE.

Comment: Thank you for answer and sorry for late response from me. I am using Gradle 2.13 and getting that error.