# Gradle DSL method not found : compile()

Tags: android

this is an older question, and i have tried many more solution but do not resolve my problem ......
[this is the error and clicking on gradle wrapper opens the upper file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ucgJ.png)

**this is app level gradle**

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.itobuz.android.awesomechat"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }

    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    //firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-config:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    //others
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.3.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.miguelcatalan:materialsearchview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton.rxrelay:rxrelay:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile project(':emoticon')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**this is project level gradle**

```js
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

kindly resolve this problem , i have wasted much time on it ..... thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried ? did you look this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617687/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-compile?rq=1 ?

Comment: yes i tried that solutions ...... my dependencies are on right gradle .....

Comment: you can check my gradles ......

Comment: In gradle-wrapper.properties, try changing gradle-3.3-all.zip to  gradle-3.3-bin.zip

Comment: it does'nt work