# ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: java, android, api, gradle

I'm trying to use yelp-fusion-android library. I tried updating the gradle but no luck.

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR: Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'
Possible causes:
The project 'testProject' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
Open Gradle wrapper file

The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
Apply Gradle plugin
```

Here is build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: what's your gradle version?

Comment: Why you are adding app dependency in your module gradle it should be in app build.gradle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unsupported Gradle DSL method found: 'compile()'!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24730117/unsupported-gradle-dsl-method-found-compile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** this line from the **top-level** file:

```
//compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'
```

In the `app/build.gradle` file you can add the same dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.5'
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here
compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'

Compile is deprecated use "Implementation" instead

and you are placing it in the wrong gradle there are 2 gradle files 
please note this warning 
// NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files

Answer (score 0):

Place below dependency in **app** module instead of main project gradle.

```
compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'
```

and replace compile with Implementation.
e.g (In **app** module)

```
Implementation 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'
```

Answer (score 0):

`dependencies` section inside `buildscript` is not for module dependencies. Hence. move out `compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'` from this section and create top level dependencies block and put it there as below:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()

}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.github.ranga543:yelp-fusion-client:0.1.4'
    }
```

Also, if you have got submodule then you can add this dependency to the sub-module.